# How to resample / downsample an irregular timestamp list?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, resampling, downsampling

SImple question but I haven't been able to find a simple answer.

I have a list of data which counts the time in seconds that events occur:

```
[200.0 420.0 560.0 1100.0 1900.0 2700.0 3400.0 3900.0 4234.2 4800.0 etc..]
```

I want to count how many events occur each hour (3600 seconds) and create a new list of these counts.

I understand this is called downsampling, but all the information I can find is related to traditional time series.

For the example above the new list would look like:

```
[7 3 etc..]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_events = [
    200.0, 420.0, 560.0, 1100.0, 1900.0, 2700.0, 3400.0, 3900.0, 4234.2, 4800.0]

def get_events_by_hour(all_events):
    return [
        len([x for x in all_events if int(x/3600.0) == hour]) 
        for hour in xrange(24)
    ]

print get_events_by_hour(all_events)
```

Note that all_events should contain events for one day.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. Any way to remove the hour stamp in the output, that is, the "0:" "1:" part of the output?

Answer (score 1):

The act of sampling means taking data `f_i` (samples) at certain discrete times `t_i`.
The number of samples per time unit gives the sampling rate.
Downsampling is a special case of resampling, which means mapping the sampled data onto a different set of sampling points `t_i'`, here onto one with a smaller sampling rate, making the sample more coarse.

Your first list is containing sample points `t_i` (unit is seconds), and indirectly the number of events `n_i` which corresponds to the index `i`, for example `n_i = i + 1`.

If you reduce the list once in a while, after a periodic time `T` (unit is seconds), you are resampling to a new set `n_i'` at times `t_i' = i * T`.
I did not write downsampling, because nothing might happen within an the time `T`, which means upsampling, because you take more data points now.

For calculation you check if the input list is empty, in that case `n' = 0` should go into your output list.
Otherwise you have `m` entries in your input list, measured over time `T` and you can use the below equation:

`n' = m * 3600 / T`

The above `n'` would go into your output list, this is scaled to events per hour.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful info. I didn't realise that a count of 0 would be classed as upsampling!

Answer (score 1):

The question has the `scipy` tag, and `scipy` depends on `numpy`, so I assume an answer using `numpy` is acceptable.

To get the hour associated with a timestamp `t` you can take the integer part of `t/3600`.  Then, to get the number of events in each hour, you can count the number of occurrences of these integers.  The numpy function [`bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) can do that for you.

Here's a numpy one-liner for the calculation.  I put the timestamps in a numpy array `t`:

```
In [49]: t = numpy.array([200.0, 420.0, 560.0, 1100.0, 1900.0, 2700.0, 3400.0, 3900.0, 4234.2, 4800.0, 8300.0, 8400.0, 9500.0, 10000.0, 14321.0, 15999.0, 16789.0, 17000.0])

In [50]: t
Out[50]: 
array([   200. ,    420. ,    560. ,   1100. ,   1900. ,   2700. ,
         3400. ,   3900. ,   4234.2,   4800. ,   8300. ,   8400. ,
         9500. ,  10000. ,  14321. ,  15999. ,  16789. ,  17000. ])
```

Here's your calculation:

```
In [51]: numpy.bincount((t/3600).astype(int))
Out[51]: array([7, 3, 4, 1, 3])
```